# Can't parse date in TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, date-parsing

I have a string that is *almost* a properly formatted date:  `"Fri Sep 21 201800:34:27 GMT"`.  The *almost* is because there's not a space between the four digit year and the beginning of the time.  That *should* be easy to split up and manage to parse via something like this:

```
var text = "Fri Sep 21 201800:34:27 GMT";
var colonAt = text.indexOf(':')
var date = [text.substr(0, colonAt-2), text.substr(colonAt-2)].join(' ')
```

This correctly returns a string that looks like `"Fri Sep 21 2018 00:34:27 GMT"` which *should* be valid.  If I pass this to `Date.parse` in my console, it *works*.  But, if I pass this string to `Date.parse` in a TamperMonkey script, I get `NaN`.  Am I being dense, or is there some trick to parsing dates in TamperMonkey scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  Turns out there's a non-breaking space embedded before the time zone when I retrieve the value programmatically.  By adding `.replace("\u00A0", " ")` after the `.join(" ")` addresses the issue.

For those curious, I found it by using `encodeURI(text)`.  That spit out `%C2%A0` between the seconds and the timezone.  A few searches later and I had an explanation and a way to get it working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what caused you to consider the fact it could be a non-breaking space?

Comment: A hunch that it had to be a non-printing character that I wasn't picking up when I copy/pasted the value into my console for testing.